# Images and Filters in OpenCL

Tags: c, image, opencl

Lets say I have an image called Test.jpg.

I just figured out how to bring an image into the project by the following line:

```
FILE *infile = fopen("Stonehenge.jpg", "rb");
```

Now that I have the file, do I need to convert this file into a bmp image in order to apply a filter to it?

I have never worked with images before, let alone OpenCl so there is a lot that is going over my head.

**I need further clarification on this part for my own understanding**

Does this bmp image also need to be stored in an array in order to have a filter applied to it? I have seen a sliding window technique be used a couple of times in other examples. Is the bmp image pretty much split up into RGB values (0-255)? If someone can provide a link on this item that should help me understand this a lot better.

I know this may seem like a basic question to most but I do not have a mentor on this subject in my workplace.

Comment: If you insist to use jpg,  you need to decode it into byte array. Usually a easier way to get started is to convert jpg into raw byte array using an external image converter tool and load the raw byte array file directly into memory.

Comment: As per datenwolfs answer below, won't the pictures size be way too big to hold in memory if the image is huge?

Comment: @VedhaR: HUGE means, by far larger than what fits into your computer's RAM and can be rearranged in a way that each pixels surroundings won't fit either. A modern computer will have several GiB of RAM around. If your image is 2D, 3 channels and 8 bits per component you'd need over 15000 pixels square to consume over 2GiB. Just to give you an idea what "HUGE" means.

Comment: It depends on the memory size and image size. If you consider a consumer digital camera, which is around 24M pixels, 3 byte per pixel, it's well below the memory capacity of current generation of mainstream computers. However images can be as large as satellite images, computers can be as small as a SD card controller, so, hard to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now that I have the file, do I need to convert this file into a bmp image in order to apply a filter to it?

Not exactly. `bmp` is a very specific image serialization format and actually a quite complicated one (implementing a BMP file parser that deals with all the corner cases correctly is actually rather difficult).

However what you have there so far is not even file content data. What you have there is a C stdio `FILE` handle and that's it. So far you did not even check if the file could be opened. That's not really useful.

JPEG is a lossy compressed image format. What you need to be able to "work" with it is a pixel value array. Either an array of component tuples, or a number of arrays, one for each component (depending on your application either format may perform better).

Now implementing image format decoders becomes tedious. It's not exactly difficult but also not something you can write down on a single evening. Of course the devil is in the details and writing an implementation that is high quality, covers all corner cases and is fast is a major effort. That's why for every image (and video and audio) format out there you usually can find only a small number of encoder and decoder implementations. The de-facto standard codec library for JPEG are libjpeg and libjpeg-turbo. If your aim is to read *just* JPEG files, then these libraries would be the go-to implementation. However you also may want to support PNG files, and then maybe EXR and so on and then things become tedious again. So there are meta-libraries which wrap all those format specific libraries and offer them through a universal API.

In the OpenGL wiki there's a dedicated page on the current state of image loader libraries: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Libraries

> Does this bmp image also need to be stored in an array in order to have a filter applied to it?

That actually depends on the kind of filter you want to apply. A simple threshold filter for example does not take a pixel's surroundings into account. If you were to perform scanline signal processing (e.g. when processing old analogue television signals) you may require only a single row of pixels at a time.

The universal solution of course to keep the whole image in memory, but then some pictures are *so* HUGE that no average computer's RAM can hold them. There are image processing libraries like [VIPS](http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk/index.php?title=VIPS) that implement processing graphs that can operate on small subregions of an image at a time and can be executed independently.

> Is the bmp image pretty much split up into RGB values (0-255)? If someone can provide a link on this item that should help me understand this a lot better.

In case you mean "pixel array" instead of BMP (remember, BMP is a specific data structure), then no. Pixel component values may be of any scalar type and value range. And there are in fact colour spaces in which there are value regions which are mathematically necessary but do not denote actually sensible colours.

When it comes down to pixel data, an image is just a n-dimensional array of scalar component tuples where each component's value lies in a given range of values. It doesn't get more specific for that. Only when you introduce colour spaces (RGB, CMYK, YUV, CIE-Lab, CIE-XYZ, etc.) you give those values specific colour-meaning. And the choice of data type is more or less arbitrary. You can either use 8 bits per component RGB (0..255), 10 bits (0..1024) or floating point (0.0 .. 1.0); the choice is yours.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain my doubts. You have cleared up a lot for me. Do you think its possible to just add a filter to an image through OpenCL? (Rather than using OpenGL)

Comment: OpenCL has about the same amount of support for reading, decoding, encoding and write image files as OpenGL: None. Implementing a filter is about as difficult/easy in OpenCL as in OpenGL, but there's no ready to use filter framework in either. If you need something that's a little bit more accessible have a look at OpenCV, which internally uses OpenCL to GPU accelerate image operations where suitable. Most importantly OpenCV comes with ready to use image file readers/writers **and** a image filtering framework. If you want to get results quickly I strongly suggest you use OpenCV

Comment: @VedhaR: Just to give you an idea: This is a tutorial on how to apply a smoothing filter on an image read from a file: http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/dd3/tutorial_gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter.html – as you can see it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Oh sweet, I'll take a look at that tutorial. My end goal for all of this is to actually do some signal processing through OpenCL and an FPGA. I just figured learning about filters and how they affect images may be a good start. (That's why I am so keen on sticking with OpenCL, I don't think I will be using OpenGL or CV for the FPGA)

Comment: @VedhaR: You'll be hard pressed to actually find a OpenGL implementation for a FPGA (not impossible, but not reasonable; GPUs are cheaper and made for the job). Altera has a OpenCL implementation that targets FPGAs and as already told, OpenCV can use OpenCL as a computation backend. Thus you may be able to use OpenCV's CL backend in combination with the Altera OpenCL implementation to target a FPGA.

Comment: Respect to your detailed answer, under such a vague question.

Comment: @DarkZeros: Once you've been tutoring newbies for long enough you learn how to extract the actual doubts from vague questions. In my experience there arw two kinds of newbies: Wannabees (who throw around buzzwords without any idea of what they actually have to look for) and Inquirers, who are generally interested and eager to learn, but lack the knowledge of the common jargon (which makes using search engines efficiently quite difficult) and/or a general idea of what to look for in the first place. The latter will ask questions which read vague, but are actually rather specific.